# Diseño no se adapta a mobile

Tags: html, css3, responsive

lo que pasa es que al probar los diseños con chrome en inspeccionar elemento, al probar con iphone 6 y los otros que tiene se ve bien, pero al mirarlo ya en mi teléfono no agarra la altura, los tamaños de texto etc los agarra normal

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.sliders1{
    margin-top: 145px;
    }
}
```

gracias por la ayuda

Comment: me di cuenta que al abrirla en incognito tampoco me agarra los diseños, solo me sirve sin abrirla en incognito, pero aun asi no se porque sigue igual si ya le borre el cache

Comment: Hola @Daniel Salinas acabo de probar y funciona perfectamente. Deberías poner el resto del código para ver en donde puede estar el problema. Saludos!

Comment: Mas allá de que me aparecen 422 errores en consola(algo que deberías verificar) me funciona bien aparentemente en mobile. Pero no encuentro ningún elemento al que le estés aplicando la clase "sliders1"

Comment: es sliders sin el 1, ya se lo quite, le puse el 1 solo para probar, pero sigue igual en mi cel se ve como si no tuviera el responsive, pero en el tester de chrome si ve todo bien